# NodeJS Child Process execute 2 command in the same shell

Tags: node.js, child-process

I would like to run 2 commands with nodeJS in the same shell. However, the documentation seems that it can only run a single command `child_process.spawn(command[, args][, options])`

The reason 2 commands have to be executed in the same shell is because the first script would write into the environment and the second script will read from it.

This is an example of the script but I would like both ps and grep to be in the same shell.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ps = spawn('ps', ['ax'], { shell: true });
const grep = spawn('grep', ['ssh'],{  shell: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ps.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin);
```